# Python nested functions

Tags: python, pyqt5

Absolutely newbie in Python.
Statement is satisfied as user exist in DB so program prints "DETAILS CORRECT" but also I would like it to jump to next window (made in PyQt5) by going through next function. Is that correct? def function2

```
    else:
        cur = conn.cursor()
        query = 'SELECT customer_password FROM customers_table WHERE customer_login =\'' + customerlogin + "\'"
        cur.execute(query)
        result_pass = cur.fetchone()[0]
        if result_pass == customerpassword:
            def function2():   
        self.errorlabel.setText("DETAILS CORRECT")
        else:
            self.errorlabel.setText("PLEASE CHECK DATA OR REGISTER")
```

Comment: What is your issue regarding the code? Does it work according to your expectation?

Answer (score 2):

You need to call the function not define it, you define it somewhere else:

```
def func2():
    ...

...

if result_pass == customerpassword:
    self.errorlabel.setText("DETAILS CORRECT")
    func2()     
else:
    self.errorlabel.setText("PLEASE CHECK DATA OR REGISTER")
```